# Copy and Paste within a step (MacOSX, Behat 2.5.3, Chromedriver)

Tags: php, jquery, macos, selenium-chromedriver, behat

We have a bug where customers pasting items from MS Word encounter a formatting error within a form, and we have implemented a fix for this.

But, alas, there is a problem with automating the copy and paste.

The only way to test it would be to do a copy and paste, within a step (as the IDE we are using doesn't reformat the text that is throwing an error).

In the case that we have, we are using quotes, so I've taken the liberty of removing them within the new paste step definition, as shown here:

```
   /**
     * @Then /^I paste in textbox "([^"]*)" with (.*)$/
     */
    public
    function iPasteInTextboxWith($selector, $value)
    {
        $element = $this->getSession()->getPage()->find("css", $selector);
        $element->setValue($value);

        $this->getSession()->evaluateScript('(function(){
                    $("' . $selector . '").trigger("focus");
                    $("' . $selector . '").trigger("paste");
                    $("' . $selector . '").trigger("change");
                    $("' . $selector . '").trigger("blur");
             })()');

    }
```

This should work, because we are using a JQuery listener to trigger the changing of Word to the standard, and it works perfectly when manually testing, however it refuses to trigger when the scenario is running.

Is there anything that could help in this situation?